How to reset Django 4 template cache without VPS restart
When I changed my html templates in Django 4.2.7, changed not apply. I have to reboot the VPS. How to fix this?
Is it possible somehow through manage.py reset the template cache. Or in some other convenient way.
By standard means. There was no such problem on the local machine during the development of the site.

I presume this is AWS?
